# Has a Star Trek doctor ever been randomly injured in an attack?

Tags: star-trek

My question is only about Drs. McCoy, Crusher, Pulaski, Bashir & Phlox.

Have any of them been *randomly* injured in an on-screen attack? Examples of events I am discounting:

- Dr Pulaski being accidentally infected by the advanced humans when she was treating one of them. [TNG: Unnatural Selection](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnatural_Selection_(episode))
- Dr Bashir being taken over by Vantika. [DS9: The Passenger](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Passenger_(episode))
- Dr Phlox being infected by a Borg. [ENT: Regeneration](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Regeneration_(episode))

All of these events happened *because* they were doctors, so were in vulnerable positions. I want to know if their ship/station/other posting was attacked and they were injured despite not being specifically targeted.

I am also discounting Voyager because their human doctor was killed in the first episode before becoming a main character, and whenever the EMH is "injured" he needs to be fixed by Torres who is an engineer, not a doctor damn it!

Comment: Though eventually reversed, Dr Crusher in Timescape https://www.google.com/search?q=tng+timescape+crusher&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS614US615&hl=en-US&prmd=svin&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxz6eSivnLAhXGeCYKHa1NCJQQ_AUICigD&biw=320&bih=492#imgrc=_1zNmiTzjZuarM%3A

Comment: Also pretty sure McCoy gets zapped by God in Star Trek V

Comment: Was that God? What does God need with a starship?

Comment: I understand why you're discounting Voyager's EMH, but wouldn't the human doctor who died in that episode fit your criteria?

Comment: @Alarion : Out of universe, that doctor was specifically targeted by the writers to help explain the EMH's position of being a full-time doctor despite not being designed for that role, which was a critical part of the character's basic definition.

Comment: @Alarion I'm not sure I understand why the Doctor (EMH) is being discounted.  Is this some kind of discrimination against holograms?  There certainly have been instances where the Doctor has been injured...

Comment: Does Crusher get injured during *Chain of Command*? In Part 2, she's being examined in sickbay after returning from her mission with Worf to the Enterprise. I don't think she gets injured, but I'm not entirely sure. A cave partially collapses on her, and she's involved in a firefight, so there's a chance. She's recruited for this mission for her scientific skills and knowledge and not for medical reasons, so she'd count in this instance if she sustains any injuries.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Yes.

In *TNG* ["Arsenal of Freedom"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Arsenal_of_Freedom_(episode)), Dr. Crusher was injured in an away mission with Picard, Data, Riker, and Yar present.

The ground gave way beneath her and Picard and she was badly injured.

An alien weapon had been attacking the group at the time (after encasing Riker in some kind of bubble), but it was not targeting Crusher specifically and her predicament had nothing to do with her being a doctor.

[image]

Comment: Great example; now I need to think of one!

Comment: Got one, although not as good as yours!

Comment: @N_Soong : I like it, +1!  :-)

Comment: @N_Soong You've both got good examples! I was thinking that the doctors never get injured because there's no-one else who could treat them and obviously Crusher is head of a large medical team so she can be treated by one of her staff, in those cases when she's not killed.

Comment: ...but had *everything* to do with her being a potential love interest for Picard.

Answer (score 24):

Also, Crusher was technically killed in *TNG* 'Timescape'.  She was killed, but you could argue she wasn't technically injured, because it was reversed (weird time-travel happened!)

[image]

Now, this actually *was* an accident, as explained on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Timescape_(episode)):

> In sickbay, Troi pulls Dr. Crusher out of the way just as the Romulan fires his disruptor, aiming her phaser at him. **Dr. Crusher explains to Troi that he wasn't firing at her. The Romulan officer explains that he was shooting at an alien who had taken Romulan form and the doctor got in the way.**

So, although there were (deadly) injuries sustained by Crusher, they weren't intentional!

Comment: It’s funny to see how unaligned the weapon and beam are. It makes someone wonder how to hit a target at anything farther than an arm’s length.

Comment: @Holger obviously it aims for the centre of mass of the object you are mentally targeting.

Comment: @Holger but is it so aligned?  To me, it looks like the gun is rather wide, and that Crusher is slightly closer to the camera... from my time-pressured hurried quick glance, it looks rather right.

Comment: @TOOGAM: to me it looks like the weapon points to her heart whereas the beam points to her stomach. Regardless of where they are standing, no perspective issue should ever convert a straight line to something having a kink in it (besides painting the beam on the image in the post-processing and being not good at the job). And it has a kink, you can easily verify with a ruler if your plain eye doesn’t see it.

Comment: @OrangeDog: indeed that magically-finding-center-of-mass feature could be related to the magically-knowing-how-much-to-desintegrate feature of phasers in destroy mode. What I like most about it is that shooters can miss their target, but whatever they hit then, the phaser will understand what makes to-destroy parts of the composed object and what are just touching but unrelated objects.

Comment: @Holger I'd give the VFX artist the benefit of the doubt and suggest that rather than being bad at their job, they realised what it would look like if they moved the effect higher up Ms. McFadden's torso.

Comment: Wibbly wobbly, timey wimey...

Comment: @Holger It's possible that the beam exits at a consistent angle from the emitter that is not the same as the apparent line of the body of the weapon, and that the users are trained to sight the weapon in a way that allows them to target the beam with this in mind.

Answer (score 12):

**Dr McCoy** was killed in *Shore Leave* but I don't know if you'd call it an accident. He stood in front of a charging knight and was speared.

[image]

He did get better, though.

[image]

He also accidently shoots himself up with a drug in TOS *City on the Edge of Forever* - causing him to go crazy and change Earth's history.

He was also tortured in *The Empath* but that was no accident.

[image]

Comment: That "He did get better though" picture...OMG. Yes, aside from the picture, no more needed to be said.

Comment: @T.E.D. Are they wearing tribbles?

Comment: @CJDennis - ...by the end of the episode they'd look like they were wearing furry parkas.